# user getting unauthorized on login in quickblox

Tags: quickblox, quickblox-android

I have been using quickblox starter pack since few weeks. From last couple of days i am facing an issue, when user tries to log in he is getting response as unauthorized though credentials provided are correct and used to login successfully. what could be the problem?

here is the response

```
** RESPONSE ** aee2f74a - 60 d0 - 479 b - 8e bc - 2 d658f33e284 **
 * STATUS: 401 HEADERS X - Runtime = 0.024496 Cache - Control = no - cache 
QuickBlox - REST - API - Version = 0.1 .1 X - Android - Selected - Protocol = 
http / 1.1 Set - Cookie = _mkra_ctxt = 1 c7505dc841a4211883a8ea75d8d0c87- 
-401;
path = /; max-age=5; HttpOnly; secure        WWW-Authenticate=OAuth 
ealm=auth        QB-Token-ExpirationDate=2018-07-13 20:27:07 UTC        
Status=401 Unauthorized        X-Request-Id=20cc6431-5fdb-4a5c-9e1a- 
36aebbfad789        X-Android-Response-Source=NETWORK 401        
Connection=Close        X-Android-Sent-Millis=1531506426961        Content- 
Type=application/json;
charset = utf - 8 Date = Fri, 13 Jul 2018 18: 27: 07 GMT X - Content - Type - 
Options = nosniff Server = openresty / 1.9 .15 .1 Content - Length = 27 
Strict - Transport - Security = max - age = 31536000 X - XSS - Protection = 
1;
mode = block X - Frame - Options = SAMEORIGIN X - Android - Received - Millis 
= 1531506427648 Access - Control - Allow - Origin = * BODY '{"errors": 
["Unauthorized"]}'
```

Comment: i also got this error, have u find any solution?

Comment: @YogendraPatel strangely it started working normally like it used to.. i guess the problem might be at their side. Did you manage to work it again?

Comment: also facing the same issue now